# Add google maps directions within android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, driving-directions

I want to implement the below card (with drive/transit images used by the google maps application). When the drive icon is clicked i want to implement the maps showing the driving directions within my app itself. I have read through the documentation but i am not sure if it is even possible. Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Look at the [Google Maps APIs terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions) and you will see this: `No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.`

Comment: @DanielNugent but how does uber and ola cabs showing there logo in google maps direction screen?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to make driving direction in android google map using polyline.

Check this link.

http://www.androidtrainee.com/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/